# graph component in GTK/Qt (like in blueJ)

Tags: qt, user-interface, gtk, components, uml

I'm about to make a program (qt/gtk) where I need to display some kind of UML diagrams (like in BlueJ),
I wanted to ask you if there is such a component in GTK

It must work with new version of Gtk - gi.repository

The name of library is enough for me, I'll read docs, but if somebody post here some simple demo, it'll be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [gaphas](https://github.com/amolenaar/gaphas)

Answer (score 1):

[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) ([Old homepage](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)) is a GTK based UML drawing tool. It is a very good tool with a lot of options. It is available on a number distros from their repositories. It has both application & library (libdia) components. There are python bindings available as well. If you have not checked it out, you should.
Hope this helps!

Comment: this looks like a way to go, but I still can't find how can I integrate dia to my gtk app, I just see generation of some images, etc.

Comment: @JanVorcak: Do you want to able to draw UML diagrams in your app? Or display UML diagrams? If you want to display UML diagrams, how are they saved as, images, xml or other formats?

Comment: I want tool to display/save uml diagrams, if you look at java's bluej program ... I need something like that, be able to drag classes, etc.

Comment: @JanVorcak: I did look @ bluej. Dia does a lot the same things. Hmm about integrating with your app, I am not too sure. I have not actually worked on dia as such, but one possibility is that you can get the source of dia & tailor it so that you application can display the grid & toolbar of dia.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [GooCanvas](https://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas), I think is the more complete library for that kind of work.

Answer (score -1):

I use python and pygtk, and use matplotlib to draw graphs in the GUI.

See a sample here : http://www.serpia.org/blog/2007/nov/03/matplotlib-and-pygtk-app/

Comment: I draw allsort of stuff with matplotlib. It even displays pictures.